# PCB ground plane noise

Tags: pcb, noise, buck, grounding, tl494

I have designed PCB for my buck converter.

[image]

When designing the PCB I've created, I have made one ground plane as shown.

[image]

I received the PCBs and there was noise in the TL494 affecting fixed 5V Vref that feeds into the error op-amp. It came to my attention that the noise is coming from the common ground plane connecting the TL494 ground with the ground of the gate circuitry and the MOSFET and the capacitors at the source of the MOSFET.

My question is how can I fix that? Do I just split the ground plane into two and connect them with a wire and place a decoupling capacitor that connects the two ground planes into Vcc? Just like this

[image]

Will this solve the ground noise issue?

Comment: Try connecting ground directly to the source of the MOSFET.

Comment: How did you verify the ground shift noise as the cause?  How short was your probe gnd connection? 1 cm?  Did you try adding 1nF on Vref?  Can you describe or show the noise result?  Is C5 low ESR?

Comment: Some hints to make the schematic even more clear: connect C2 directly to a GND-power symbol, same for pin 1 & 2 of IC1, mirror Q2 horizontally.

Comment: You connected pin 15 of IC1 via R3 and R1 to Vcc on purpose? I fail to see what kind of feedback you implemented (may be my lack).

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 the noise was on Vref where there were small voltage spikes which affected Vref the 5V constant voltage signal. I've placed the probe gnd on the MOSFET gnd. I am not sure where these spikes are coming from so I was suspecting noise from the gnd plane.

Comment: DO NOT split the ground plane! That will only make noise worse

Comment: @Huisman I've connected pin R1 to Vcc because I want to step the voltage down of my supply source (PV panel MSX-10) from 15-18V down to 5V. R3 is connected to pin 15 because that will give me an integral controller and Rf is there to produce a PI controller. I am trying to control my input voltage by having a PI controller at the input. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/41421.pdf

Comment: @DerStrom8 why does it make the noise worse? Wouldn't having one gnd plane allow all the noise to travel back to the TL494?

Comment: you may have high slew-rate magnetic interference or electric-displacement-current interference. Use a 1" by 1" piece of copper foil, grounded to your place with a 2" wire, thick wire, and place the 1by1 between various components, to explore possible coupling paths.

Comment: Having a split in the ground plane causes it to act like a slot antenna and emits and picks up even more noise.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Scrap your existing design.

Step 2: Read the TI data sheet for the TL494. Especially read through the "Layout" section near the end. There is a PCB layout example in that section though it is only a partial design. Here is TI's page with the full datasheet and application notes: http://www.ti.com/product/TL494

Step 3: Start a new schematic. Draw the schematic with the datasheet layout information in mind. Obviously the schematic does not need to define the final PCB layout but try to draw it as if it did. When done in this way later PCB design decisions such as component placement and trace positioning can be guided by the way you drew the schematic. As in the datasheet layout suggestions keep high current lines short, thick, and away from sensitive low current control/feedback lines.

Breaking the ground plane up sometimes helps, but it can also complicate some of the design. Consider making the ground plane with only a partial divider but still keep a wide connection between each side. The high current components and traces will stay on one side and the low current sensitive parts on the other. Be sure to place decoupling caps where the datasheet recommends.

As a final thought, note the pin arrangement of the chip itself, certain function pins are grouped to one side (for e.g. 1 thru 6, and 15, 16), this is done purposely and gives you additional hints to the suggested physical layout.

For even more help here is an older StackExchange Q/A that went into some complex details of a TL494 design. The design is relatively close to yours and a PCB layout is included. [Buck converter, squeaking/whining inductor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/420735/buck-converter-squeaking-whining-inductor)